# @Caching With Multiple Keys

Tags: java, spring, caching, methods

I have a service that takes in a DTO and returns some result:

```
@Override
public int foo(Bar bar) {
    ....
}
```

Bar is as follows (simplified):

```
public class Bar {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String baz;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //this is already being defined for something else
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        //this is already being defined for something else
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to use @Cacheable on the foo method; however, I want to hash on the id and name properties, but not baz.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Cacheable key on multiple method arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072380/cacheable-key-on-multiple-method-arguments)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can specify using a Spring-EL expression along these lines:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(key="#bar.name.concat('-').concat(#bar.id)")
public int foo(Bar bar) {
    ....
}
```

or define a modified hashCode on bar and call that:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(key="#bar.hashCodeWithIdName")
public int foo(Bar bar) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: If '-' is public static final String data. How should I do?

Comment: Be careful on the NullPointerException in case name or id are null

Answer (score 57):

You can use this approach also

```
@Override
@Cacheable(key="{#bar.name, #bar.id}")
public int foo(Bar bar) {
    ....
}
```

It is suggested not to use hashcode as keys
[@Cacheable key on multiple method arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072380/cacheable-key-on-multiple-method-arguments)

Comment: But when I use this approach it's throwing `java.lang.ClassCastException: Invalid key type, expected : org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey but was : java.util.ArrayList`. How can I get over this?

Answer (score 2):

Both answers by @Biju and @vsingh are correct; but I would like to add one more alternative if the `Bar` object you are trying to cache is complex or the `foo` method contains a large amount of parameters using SpEL might not be the most ideal solution for generating the key.

Alternatively you may want to consider `keyGenerator`.

Example:

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value="barCahceKey", keyGenerator="barKeyGenerator")
public int foo(Bar bar) {
  ....
}

@Component
public class BarKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {
@Override
public Object generate(Object o, Method method, Object... objects) {
      // TODO logic to generate unique key
      return "Bar_Key_Generator_With_Params_etc";
    }
}
```

With this approach you have the fully flexibility of how the key is constructed.

[KeyGenerator API](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/KeyGenerator.html)

Comment: Custom keyGenerator allow to create only 1 key. What about having multipe keys from KeyGenerator? This KeyGenerator only return Object not array of object. So, I guess custom KeyGenerator cannot be used for multiple key generation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring SimpleKey class

```
@Cacheable(value = "barCache", key = "new org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey(#bar.id, #bar.name)")
```

Comment: This works for but why does [@vsingh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24193252/9079093) solution gives me `java.lang.ClassCastException: Invalid key type, expected : org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey but was : java.util.ArrayList` exception?

Comment: But why does it require `key = "new org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey(#bar.id, #bar.name)"` instead of `key = "{#bar.id, #bar.name}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Cacheable(value = "myCacheByNameUserCity", key = "T(java.util.Objects).hash(#name, #user, #city)")
  public User getUser(String name, String user,String city)
```

I propose this method with Object.hash, because
*"new org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey (# bar.id, # bar.name)"* returns toString ()
So it returns:

```
getClass().getSimpleName() + " [" + StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(this.params) + "]";
```

So finally it returns "SimpleKey [bla,blaa, blalala]" not a unique code

Answer (score 0):

## Example for a KeyGenerator-implementation with multiple keys

```
public class MyKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {

  public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
    if (params.length > 2) {
        // only the first two, please! this was useful in my case.
        // omit or use like this, if (not) needed
        params = Arrays.copyOf(params, 2);
    }
    var key = String.format("mykey_%s", StringUtils.arrayToDelimitedString(params, "_")); 
    return key;
  }
}
```

In your **CacheConfig** you inject the bean like:

```
@Bean("myKeyGenerator") KeyGenerator myKeyGenerator() {
    return new MyCacheKeyGenerator();
}
```

And in your **repository**-class like:

```
// assuming you also defined a "myCache" in your cache-config!

@Cacheable(value = "myCache", keyGenerator = "myKeyGenerator", unless="#result == null")
public byte[] getMyData(int objectId, int objectType, boolean furtherParams, int willBeIgnored) {
}

@CacheEvict(value = "myCache", keyGenerator = "myKeyGenerator")
public void storeMyData(int id, int type, byte[] myData, int changingUserId) {
   // store here and do the same annotation for the delete-method
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The keys from the same Object, you can use object.hashCode(), so you don't need to specific keys one by one

```
@Override
@Cacheable(key="#bar.hashCode()")
public int foo(Bar bar) {
    ....
}
```

OR if you have an object and another key

```
@Override
@Cacheable(key="{#bar.hashCode(), #anotherKey}")
public int foo(Bar bar) {
    ....
}
```

I think this is a better solution.

Comment: Hash codes are dangerous as they aren't guaranteed to be unique.