# @Cacheable key on multiple method arguments

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

From the [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) :

```
@Cacheable(value="bookCache", key="isbn")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

How can I specify `@Cachable` to use `isbn` and `checkWarehouse` as key?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

***Update***: Current Spring cache implementation uses all method parameters as the cache key if not specified otherwise. If you want to use selected keys, refer to [Arjan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17406598/241986) which uses SpEL list `{#isbn, #includeUsed}`  which is the simplest way to create unique keys.

From [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)

> The default key generation strategy changed with the release of Spring
> 4.0. Earlier versions of Spring used a key generation strategy that, for multiple key parameters, only considered the hashCode() of
> parameters and not equals(); this could cause unexpected key
> collisions (see SPR-10237 for background). The new
> 'SimpleKeyGenerator' uses a compound key for such scenarios.

**Before Spring 4.0**

I suggest you to concat the values of the parameters in Spel expression with something like `key="#checkWarehouse.toString() + #isbn.toString()")`, I believe this should work as org.springframework.cache.interceptor.ExpressionEvaluator returns Object, which is later used as the key so you don't have to provide an `int` in your SPEL expression.

As for the hash code with a high collision probability - you *can't* use it as the key.

Someone in this thread has suggested to use `T(java.util.Objects).hash(#p0,#p1, #p2)` but it WILL NOT WORK and this approach is easy to break, for example I've used the data from [SPR-9377](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9377) :

```
    System.out.println( Objects.hash("someisbn", new Integer(109), new Integer(434)));
    System.out.println( Objects.hash("someisbn", new Integer(110), new Integer(403)));
```

Both lines print -636517714 on my environment.

P.S. Actually in the reference documentation we have

```
@Cacheable(value="books", key="T(someType).hash(#isbn)") 
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)
```

I think that this example is WRONG and misleading and should be removed from the documentation, as the keys should be unique.

P.P.S. also see https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9036 for some interesting ideas regarding the default key generation.

I'd like to add for the sake of correctness and as an entertaining mathematical/computer science fact that unlike built-in hash, using a *secure* [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) like MD5 or SHA256, due to the properties of such function *IS* absolutely possible for this task, but to compute it every time may be too expensive, checkout for example Dan Boneh cryptography course to learn more.

Comment: hmm i think spr-9036 ignores the situation where a parameter is an array, as arrays do not do deep equals by default

Comment: Does this answer about key weekness actual for spring version `3.1.1`? [SPR-9377](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9377) was fixed for `3.1.1`, no? Could somebody add **UPDATED** section for this answer?

Comment: Also does `T(someType).hash(#isbn)` work in Spring `3.1.1`?

Comment: @Cherry Try using Arjan's answer ( `{ #root.methodName, #param1, #param2 }`, anyway 3.1.1 is old version now.

Comment: Old, but I have to use it now :) So using Spring 3.2 is not sutable for me :( Yes there are plans for migration, but not right now. So actualization about this is important for me any other who still use old version.

Comment: @Cherry are you sure that Arjan's solution is not working? If it's not, then you can just concat the string values anyway.

Comment: how does it use all params, by toString?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Arrays.deepEquals() - for objects in general it will end up with Object.equals(). Using toString() would add memory footprint and it's counterintuitive as every Object has equals() method in Java

Comment: how will equals method generate a cache key? dont you have to first get an object out of the map?

Answer (score 101):

After some limited testing with Spring 3.2, it seems one can use a SpEL list: `{..., ..., ...}`. This can also include `null` values. Spring passes the list as the key to the actual cache implementation. When using Ehcache, such will at some point invoke [List#hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode%28%29), which takes all its items into account. (I am not sure if Ehcache *only* relies on the hash code.)

I use this for a shared cache, in which I [include the method name](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-spel-context) in the key as well, which the Spring default key generator [does not include](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/DefaultKeyGenerator.java). This way I can easily wipe the (single) cache, without (too much...) risking matching keys for different methods. Like:

```
@Cacheable(value="bookCache", 
  key="{ #root.methodName, #isbn?.id, #checkWarehouse }")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse) 
...

@Cacheable(value="bookCache", 
  key="{ #root.methodName, #asin, #checkWarehouse }")
public Book findBookByAmazonId(String asin, boolean checkWarehouse)
...
```

Of course, if many methods need this and you're always using all parameters for your key, then one can also define a custom key generator that includes the class and method name:

```
<cache:annotation-driven mode="..." key-generator="cacheKeyGenerator" />
<bean id="cacheKeyGenerator" class="net.example.cache.CacheKeyGenerator" />
```

...with:

```
public class CacheKeyGenerator 
  implements org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator {

    @Override
    public Object generate(final Object target, final Method method, 
      final Object... params) {

        final List<Object> key = new ArrayList<>();
        key.add(method.getDeclaringClass().getName());
        key.add(method.getName());

        for (final Object o : params) {
            key.add(o);
        }
        return key;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I get the custom KeyGenerator to be picked up in a xml-free configuration?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to `{..., ..., ...}`. In the [current documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key) it says that the default key generation will consider all parameters. So no need to create `CacheKeyGenerator`.

Comment: If this is not working for you, maybe your code does not know argument names, so use #a0 instead of #asin , a1 instead of #checkWarehouse etc. (also #p0, #p1). This happens for me in spring-data-jpa

Comment: A _bit_ late, @linqu, but the default key generator does not include the method name. If one wants to use a single cache for multiple methods, then one needs to include the method name, if two methods can have the same parameters.

Comment: A bit late for the first comment in this section (by @basil), but this page would help:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-custom-keygenerator

Answer (score 8):

You can use a Spring-EL expression, for eg on JDK 1.7:

```
@Cacheable(value="bookCache", key="T(java.util.Objects).hash(#p0,#p1, #p2)")
```

Comment: And what about the collisions? P.S. Yes, this is what they tell to do in the reference, but the whole idea is very odd

Comment: P.P.S. actually they *don't* tell to do in the reference - the only example with hashing is `@Cacheable(value="books", key="T(someType).hash(#isbn)")
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn, boolean checkWarehouse, boolean includeUsed)` - but it seems to be a wrong and misleading example

Comment: Actually I've found a counterexample with google (see my answer)

Comment: @BorisTreukhov, the point was to show how arguments can be used to build a key using Spring-EL, not a solution which can be considered robust, I agree probably the simplest solution is to simply concatenate the arguments together which again can be done using Spring-EL.

Comment: I see, but the problem is not about which solution is simpler - the problem is that using hashcode is plain dangerous - if one client happened to get 109/434 keypair and another - 110/403 that may allow them for example to see each other's messages in the forum, or account operations in the internet-bank. I'm sure that there are a lot more collisions possible - good hash functions are hard to implement(consider looking at the source of md5 implementations - it's plain not multiplying on some magic number), and still they will never be able to return unique values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Spring SimpleKey class

```
@Cacheable(value = "bookCache", key = "new org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey(#isbn, #checkWarehouse)")
```

Comment: Does this keep increasing memory usage by filling heap causing memory leak as you are using `new` keyword here?

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
@Cacheable(value="bookCache", key="#checkwarehouse.toString().append(#isbn.toString())")
```

Comment: I used spring-data-jpa and there has to be used a0 as argument on first position istead of using its name...

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
@Cacheable(value="bookCache", key="#isbn + '_' + #checkWarehouse + '_' + #includeUsed")
```

Comment: That combination is always unique, as your are just adding the string values combinations to key..