# Spring @Cachable bean reference in key

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-el

I want to use the @Cachable annotation on one of my methods, but I have the problem, that the result depends on an attribute of a spring bean that is not part of the method signature.

So I want something like this:

```
@Cachable(value="mycache", key="#id, #myspringbean.referenceId")
MyResult myMethod(int id);
```

I guess these are actually two problems: How to get use a composite key and how to use another spring bean in the expression.

The problem of how to use a composite key can probably be solved like in this SO question: [@Cacheable key on multiple method arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072380/cacheable-key-on-multiple-method-arguments)

However, I could not find anythig about how to reference to another spring bean in this expression. Is it possible and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a lot a details on SpEL in the Spring documentation (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). As you can see, you can use bean references using the `@myBean` syntax. You have to include a bean resolver in your context to do that.

Comment: Ok, from what I see in the logs `@myBean` syntax seems to do what I want. But I do not know how to include a bean resolver in my context. Can you give an example or link for it? I googled for it but could not find anything that worked...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use the current Spring bean name.
I think I would use the following pattern so that each bean object will have it's own "key-space" see also [What can be the default key generator](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9036).
As for the problem above one can use:

```
@Cachable(value="mycache", key = "{#id, #root.targetClass.getDeclaredField('attribute').get(#root.target)}")
MyResult myMethod(int id);
```

just make sure your attribute is public