# Spring @Cacheable how to configure a complex key

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, spring-cache

I have a method that returns a list and I want to cache it based on the parameters passed.The parameters are 4 and integers how can I configure this with SpEL? 
I am using spring version 4.0.6.RELEASE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [@Cacheable key on multiple method arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072380/cacheable-key-on-multiple-method-arguments)

Comment: Are you sure you need to generate a custom key and that the default (all arguments will be used) does not work for you?

Comment: Thanks!I didn't know that the default is to use all the arguments.It worked!

Comment: We should always define a key and don't consider the default in case the object has many variables which in result increase the size of cache key and the heap. More info at https://www.foreach.be/blog/spring-cache-annotations-some-tips-tricks

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this

```
@Cacheable(value ="CacheService", key="#par1 + #par2 +#par3 +#par4" )
```

Answer (score 1):

The default is to use all the parameters of the method, whose return value is cached.
For example.

```
@Cacheable(value ="CacheService")
public ReturnType methodName(int param1, int param2, int param3, int param4) {
  //method body
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class SimpleKey (org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey):

```
@Cacheable(value="getPerson", key="new SimpleKey(#id, #age, #socialSecNo)") 
public String getPerson(Integer id, Integer age, Integer socialSecNo){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this keep increasing memory usage by filling heap causing memory leak as you used `new` keyword here?