# Spring Expressions, what does it mean value="{someName}"

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am working with a Spring Boot Application that uses SpEl , it has some Redis annotations and it calls my attention the use of brackets on some expressions, i.e.:

`@Cacheable(value = "{mycache}", key = "#param")`

I can tell the SpEl expression when using # is to refer to the passed param, but for the first part `"{myCache}"` I am not sure what is the purpose of the braces.

Comment: The expression `@Cacheable(value = "{mycache}", key = "#param")` means that you are setting the value for `mycache` with `#param`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Cacheable key on multiple method arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072380/cacheable-key-on-multiple-method-arguments)

Comment: what is the source for your answer?
I just want to be sure that value for `mycache` is setting the value with `#param`.

it does have no sense at all to create a cache per each key, I do not think this is what is doing