# How can I cache by method parameter in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, redis

I use Redis for caching and have the following service method:

```
@Cacheable(value = "productCache")
@Override
public List<ProductDTO> findAllByCategory(Category category) {
    
    // code omitted 

    return productDTOList;
}
```

When I pass `categoryA` to this method, the result is cached and is kept during expiration period. If I pass `categoryB` to this method, it is retrieved from database and then kept in cache. Then if I pass `categoryA` again, it is retrieved from cache.

**1.** I am not sure if it is normal, because I just use `value` parameter ("productCache") of `@Cacheable` annotation and have no idea how it caches `categoryA` and `categoryB` results separately. Could you please explain how it works?

**2.** As mentioned on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072380/cacheable-key-on-multiple-method-arguments), there is also `key` parameter. But when using it as shown below, I think it does not make any sense and it works as above. Is that normal or am I missing something?

```
@Cacheable(value = "productCache", key="#category")
@Override
public List<ProductDTO> findAllByCategory(Category category) {
    
    // code omitted 

    return productDTOList;
}
```

**3.** Should I get cache via `Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("productCache#" + category);` ?

Comment: @M.Deinum Amigo? Any idea regarding to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caches are essentially key-value stores, where – in Spring –

- the *key* is generated from the method parameter(s)
- the *value* is the result of the method invocation

The default key generation algorithm works like this (taken right from [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.10/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key)):

> - If no params are given, return SimpleKey.EMPTY.
> - If only one param is given, return that instance.
> - If more than one param is given, return a SimpleKey that contains all parameters.
>
> This approach works well for most use-cases, as long as parameters have natural keys and implement valid hashCode() and equals() methods. If that is not the case, you need to change the strategy.

So in your example, the `category` object acts as key per default (for this to work, the `Category` class should have `hashCode()` and `equals()` implemented correctly). Writing `key="#category"` is hence redundant and has no effect. If your `Category` class would have an `id` property, you could write `key="#category.id"` however.

> Should I get cache via `Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("productCache#" + category);` ?

No, since there is no such cache. You only have one single cache named `productCache`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this wonderful explanations. Here are the points I need to be clarified >>>

Comment: **1.** *Writing key="#category" is hence redundant and has no effect.* --> What if I had `public List<ProductDTO> findAllByCategory(int categoryId) {...}` ? In that case would I have use  `@Cacheable(value = "productCache", key="#categoryId")` ?

Comment: **2.** *the key is generated from the method parameter(s)* --> If the key is generated automatically, why `key` parameter is used in `@Cacheable()` annotation?

Comment: Amigo??? Any reply pls?

Comment: You can use the `key` parameter if you want the key to be different to what is used by default.